# Getting rsync in Ansible to work with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, rsync, ansible

I want to test an [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/index.html) script using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). Everything works fine until it tries to do a rsync to the remote host:

```
- name: Install custom dev user settings
  local_action: command rsync -ave ssh roles/common/files/home/{{ item.name }} 
      {{ ansible_ssh_user }}@{{ inventory_hostname }}:/#home/
  with_items: dev_users
  when: "{{ item.custom }} == True"
  tags:
  - dev_custom
  - dev_users
  - users
```

However it fails at this point - it seems to be trying to login via password but I don't know why as it should connect to Vagrant via SSH, right (I have elided some information below with ... because it mentioned keys) ?

```
127.0.0.1> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393178896.64-215542007508316 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393178896.64-215542007508316 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393178896.64-215542007508316']
<127.0.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE command rsync -ave ssh roles/common/files/home/someUser vagrant@10.0.0.10:/#home/
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpm3BnEW TO /home/mark/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393178896.64-215542007508316/command
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=...] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-...; /usr/bin/python /home/mark/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393178896.64-215542007508316/command; rm -rf /home/mark/.ansible/tmp/ansible-1393178896.64-215542007508316/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
failed: [10.0.0.10] => (item={ ... }) => {"failed": true, "item": { ... }, "parsed": false}
invalid output was: [sudo via ansible, key=...] password: 
[sudo via ansible, key=...] password: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo via ansible, key=...] password: 
[sudo via ansible, key=...] password: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo via ansible, key=...] password: 
[sudo via ansible, key=...] password: 
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Any idea how to get around this?

I do deploy a custom key to the box via ansible before I do this e.g.:

```
- name: Place ansible authorized key
  authorized_key: user=root key="{{ lookup('file', 'root/.ssh/ansible_key.pub') }}"
  tags:
  - root
```

Comment: Yes Mark, but it seems that you're deploying your key to ~root/.ssh while you connect as 'vagrant'.

Comment: It's OK Leucos, you were a big help - this Ansible tutorial looks good https://github.com/leucos/ansible-tuto so I will work through this next. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, have fun with ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark,

If you did not deploy your ssh public key to the box (in `/home/vagrant/ssh/authorized_keys`), it's quite a normal behavior to get asked for a password. Using 'vagrant' with standard boxes should work.

If you push your key first, it would be easier to get things done after. You can find a Vagrant oriented example [here](https://github.com/leucos/ansible-tuto/blob/master/step-00/setup.yml)

It seems you set `ansible_ssh_user` properly, but make sure you also invoke your playbook with `--ask-pass --sudo`.

As a side note, the line:

```
when: "{{ item.custom }} == True"
```

could be rewritten as:

```
when: item.custom
```

Comment: Hi Leucos, thanks for the tip about when, it was useful. If I add the --ask-pass --sudo then it prompts me for my password ('vagrant') but it does work now - thanks! Can you explain any more about what is happening / why this is necessary? I looked in ansible.cfg and I had --sudo set but not --ask-pass?

Comment: Well, you have to tell ansible to ask for the sudo password. In your output above, did you had a chance to type anything after a '[sudo via ansible, key=...] password:' line or did it unfold all those lines until the end without asking ?

Answer (score 6):

I finally discovered how to fix this problem. I knew it wasn't rsync because I tested it at the command line:

```
rsync -ave ssh home/dataToSync root@10.0.0.10:/home/
```

and that worked fine. I had uploaded a key to the Vagrant box I didn't even have to log in. However the calling rsync from ansible was failing. I tried specifying a password as Leucos suggested but that didn't work. I thought about it and wondered if the problem was Ansible was trying to sudo on my local box. To see if that was the problem, I added

```
sudo: False
```

to my action and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Of course ! This is a local_action ! Sorry to have missed that :facepalm: :(

Answer (score 4):

Since Vagrant runs Ansible playbooks as the user vagrant, trying to rsync to root-owned directories will usually fail. Rather than monkeying around with assigning groups or trying to find some magically idempotent chmod/chown solution, the most robust solution I've found is just to tell Ansible to use rsync with sudo.

```yaml
- synchronize: 
    src=/local/site/
    dest=/var/www/site
    rsync_path='sudo rsync'
```

Note, Ansible's [synchronize module](http://docs.ansible.com/synchronize_module.html) wraps rsync, making these tasks much cleaner to author.

Answer (score 1):

In Ansible 2.2.1.0 this worked for me:

```
- synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: "/home/vagrant/dir1"
    dest: "/my_linux/dir1"
    recursive: yes
    delete: no
    times: yes
```

...and with this inventory (to use `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` var):

```
[vagrant1]
192.168.77.4

[vagrant1:vars]
ansible_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_private_key_file="/Users/Chilcano/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
```

Hope it helps you.